# WCF Service with security mode none

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

My WCF service works fine with Security Mode="Transport" and clientCredentialType="Windows" (with client and service on either one machine or two). But I need to put the service on the other side of a firewall where Windows Authentication is not possible. I know I can either install X.509 certs or use security="None" (to which I would add my own security protocol). But I cannot get "None" to work! I keep getting 'The socket connection was aborted' error.

Here is the config, please let me know if you spot anything. I have tried it without the 2 lines that specify clientCredentialType="none" but it makes no diff. P.S. Each time I make a config change I stop and restart both the client and the service.

SERVER CONFIG

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<services>  
  <service name="OuterService.OutCardTrx">  
      <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="OuterService.IOutCardTrx">  
          <identity>  
          <dns value="localhost"/>  
          </identity>  
      </endpoint>  
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      <host>  
        <baseAddresses>  
          <add baseAddress="net.tcp://jimt4.campus.internal:8081/PCIOutService"/>  
        </baseAddresses>  
        </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="netTcpBinding">
      <security mode="None" >
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding> 
</bindings>
```

CLIENT CONFIG:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IOutCardTrx" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="None">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
              <message clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://jimt4.campus.internal:8081/" binding="netTcpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IOutCardTrx" contract="OCS.IOutCardTrx"
           name="NetTcpBinding_IOutCardTrx">
           <identity>
              <dns value="localhost" />
           </identity>
         </endpoint>
     </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: How are you hosting your service (IIS or Self-Hosting)?  Also, you can remove the clientCredentialType settings.  They aren't used when security mode is none.

Comment: @user1185782 Is it possible to use http binding?

Answer (score 4):

Not 100% sure this is the reason, but your binding security settings don't match between the client and the service.

Note that the default security for NetTcpBinding is `Transport` (for mode).  You define `None` in your binding in the service config, but that binding is never assigned to the service endpoint, so your service is using the default settings for NetTcp.

On the other hand, you are setting the binding configuration on your client.

Try setting the binding configuration in your service endpoint like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding"
          contract="OuterService.IOutCardTrx">
```

This will assign your specified binding to the endpoint, with security set to "None".  I would also recommend changing the binding configuration name to something other than "netTcpBinding" to avoid any possible confusion.

Comment: Thank-you very much - adding bindingConfiguration="netTcpBinding" got past this issue. It was nice to stop the clock at 5 hours on this problem! This has uncovered a new error which implies the service is still not accepting securityMode="None": "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal' to type 'System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal'"

Comment: @user1185782 - That sounds like a different issue.  Where are you seeing this issue at?  Is it in your code somewhere?

Comment: This issue occurs on the server side and I see the exception in the service using svctTraceViewer.exe to show the diagnostics. The request never gets as far as my app code in the service.

Comment: My mistake, the service did get to executing my code and I was trying to echo the UserName, which of-course will not exist when securityMode="None". Thanks once again for solving my original problem - the service runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try increasing the values for MaxItemsInObjectGraph, MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxBufferPoolSize, MaxBufferSize, MaxArrayLength in both client/server configs? The default values are pretty low, try maxing them out to 2147483647.

Also try enabling tracing on the service to see further error details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I increased the settings as suggested to no avail. I enabling tracing and see the service generating this error message: Stream Security is required at http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, but no security context was negotiated. This is likely caused by the remote endpoint missing a StreamSecurityBindingElement from its binding. Most forum postings suggest this is a misleading error message. Any thoughts?